# Issue when merging datasets

Tags: r, database, dataframe, merge

I merged two datasets by using `left_join(x=X,y=Y,by=c("id","year")`.
Suppose that X has 15,000 rows and Y has 14,000 rows. The outcome of the merging, even if no warning is returned is a merged dataset with 15,001 rows. Where is this additional row coming from? Something weird is happening to the dataset. In fact, after running regressions, the results change following the merge, even though the variables from the Y dataset are not included in the regression. Unfortunately, using `anti_join` is not helpful due to the presence of many NAs (since Y is smaller than X).
Do you have any suggestions or alternatives to left_join that would still retain all the observations in X?

Comment: Check `nrow(distinct(Y, id, year))` against `nrow(Y)`, my guess they are not the same. This means that for (at least) one row in `X`, there are (at least) _two_ matching rows in `Y`.

Comment: You are right. R says nrow(Y) is 10,000 and nrow(distinct(Y,id,year)) are 9,998. How can I find out these rows?

Comment: Inferring `dplyr`, you can use `filter(Y, duplicated(id, year))` to find the second (and subsequent) row(s) for the duplicated `id`/`year` pairs. Since you are assuming that those are unique, you might want to go back either earlier in your pipeline to see when this was broken, or back to the source of the data, in order to verify/challenge your assumptions of uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicates where you are not expecting them.

```r
X <- data.frame(id=1:5, year=2021:2025, Xval=11:15)
Y <- data.frame(id=c(1:5, 5), year=c(2021:2025, 2025), Yval=21:26)
dplyr::left_join(X, Y, by = c("id", "year"))
#   id year Xval Yval
# 1  1 2021   11   21
# 2  2 2022   12   22
# 3  3 2023   13   23
# 4  4 2024   14   24
# 5  5 2025   15   25
# 6  5 2025   15   26
```

where we might have expected `nrow(X)` rows to come out of the merge.

There are many causes, but in this case we can see it by counting the number of unique `id, year` (from `by=..`) combinations in the data.

```r
nrow(dplyr::distinct(Y, id, year))
# [1] 5
nrow(Y)
# [1] 6
```

If the two are equal, then `left_join(.)` should indeed return `nrow(X)` rows.

You can see the second (and subsequent, if multiple) duplicate row(s) with this:

```r
dplyr::filter(Y, duplicated(id, year))
#   id year Yval
# 1  5 2025   26
```

or base R:

```r
subset(Y, duplicated(id, year))
#   id year Yval
# 6  5 2025   26
```

If you need to see all rows of duplicated rows, then

```r
filter(Y, duplicated(id, year)) %>%
  select(id, year) %>%
  inner_join(Y, by = c("id", "year"))
#   id year Yval
# 1  5 2025   25
# 2  5 2025   26
```

or base R

```r
subset(Y, duplicated(id, year), select = c(id, year)) |>
  merge(Y, by = c("id", "year"))
#   id year Yval
# 1  5 2025   25
# 2  5 2025   26
```